Automating Instagram Profile Insight Data Collection for Multiple Accounts
I'm currently working on an automated system that gathers Instagram profile insight data and sends it to an endpoint. However, I'm facing a challenge due to the large number of Instagram accounts I need to manage—more than 100 in total.
As a beginner in this area, I understand that utilizing the Instagram Graph API would be the most efficient approach. However, manually setting up access for each of the accounts seems like a time-consuming task.
Could anyone provide guidance on how to streamline this process? I'm looking for a clear explanation or a step-by-step guide on how to automate access to the Instagram Graph API for multiple accounts.
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
